# django-rest-passwordreset create and send token manually

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

reading the [django-rest-passwordreset](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-passwordreset/) I have not found a way to create and send the `reset_password_token` manually, meaning without the use of the endpoint created by the package.

Currently I have this implementation:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/password_reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
    ...
]
```

Then when a user requests a password reset I send an email using the Signal provided by the package:

```
@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles password reset tokens
    When a token is created, an e-mail needs to be sent to the user
    :param reset_password_token: Token Model Object
    :return:
    """
    # send an e-mail to the user
    context = {
        'email': reset_password_token.user.email,
        'reset_password_url': f"{BASE_URL}new-password?token={reset_password_token.key}"
    }
    send_reset_pwd_to_sendingblue.delay(context)
```

However, in my case, I want to programmatically create the token and send it to the user without the use of the endpoint meaning the user won't reset their password through the endpoint, rather my application will create the token and send it to the user.

How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the `django_rest_passwordreset/views.py` [here](https://github.com/anexia-it/django-rest-passwordreset/blob/master/django_rest_passwordreset/views.py#L160) and see how it generates the token and then implement it.

```
            # check if the user already has a token
            if user.password_reset_tokens.all().count() > 0:
                # yes, already has a token, re-use this token
                token = user.password_reset_tokens.all()[0]
            else:
                # no token exists, generate a new token
                token = ResetPasswordToken.objects.create(
                    user=user,
                    user_agent=request.META.get(HTTP_USER_AGENT_HEADER, ''),
                    ip_address=request.META.get(HTTP_IP_ADDRESS_HEADER, ''),
                )
```